Segregating the test results generated by Allure
I have a little problem with the test results generated by Allure.
I receive results properly.
I run tests on different levels and I use copyArtifact() to receive an aggregated result of all the stages.
My problem is that at this moment I receive it shuffled, like:
SMOKE, CRITICAL, HIGH
 |
 |- smokeA,crtiticalB,crtiticalA,highC,smokeC,highA,highB etc.

My goal is to receive them segregated, for example:
SMOKE, CRITICAL, HIGH
 |
 |- SMOKE
 |    |- smokeA
 |    |- smokeB
 |    |- smokeC
 |
 |- CRITICAL
 |    |- crtiticalA
 |    |- crtiticalB 
 |    |- crtiticalC
 |
 |- HIGH
 |    |- highA
 |    |- highB
 |    |- highC

I have to mention that I use tags on my tests, but I can not find any solution on how to properly filter them for the suggested result. Does anyone know how to write it properly?
